# repose.who-friendlyform dependency in TurboGears 2

Tags: turbogears2

I am trying to install TurboGear 2. I was following the steps given in this documentation. Link: http://toscawidgets.org/documentation/tw2.core/turbogears.html

On executing this command

```
pip install -e .
```

i got this error

```
No distributions at all found for repose.who-friendlyform>=1.0.4 (from example==0.1dev)
```

Then with this command

```
python setup.py develop
```

i got this error

```
Searching for repose.who-friendlyform>=1.0.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/repose.who-friendlyform/
Couldn't find index page for 'repose.who-friendlyform' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for repose.who-friendlyform>=1.0.4
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('repose.who-friendlyform>=1.0.4')
```

I tried to install it with easy_install but it didn't work. How can i overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you are pointing to is quite outdated, which TurboGears version are you trying to use? Latest TG versions don't depend on repoze.who-friendlyform anymore. Try to delete your virtualenv, recreate it and then install TurboGears with `pip install tg.devtools`.

You can find latest TG version documentation on http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installing-turbogears with a tutorial on using ToscaWidgets at http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/TwForms.html

Also latest ToscaWidgets documentation has been moved at http://tw2core.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If you want to experiment with TG2 and Forms there are also a bunch of runnables you can play with: http://runnable.com/TurboGears